# Concatenate multiple results to one field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16257701/807032) gotten well on my way to getting my invoices put together in a nice easy to look at table. Something I've normally done manually but I'd like to do automagically is list out how many of what items are on an invoice. Manually I look over the invoice and see that a dog stayed at the kennel for 3 days and got a bath, so I'd put something like `3 Board, 1 Bath` in my spreadsheet.

The table I have has these listed (`InvoiceItems.IIItemQuantity` and `InvoiceItems.IIItemCodeDesc`), as well as what invoice they belong to (`InvoiceItems.IIInvSeq`).

So the information I'd like to add to my other query looks like this:

```
QUANTITY | ITEMDESC | INVOICE | PETID
---------|----------|---------|------
    3    |   BOARD  |  12344  |  12
    1    |    BATH  |  12344  |  12
    4    |   BOARD  |  12345  |  14
    4    |    PLAY  |  12345  |  14
    1    |    BATH  |  12345  |  14
    4    |   BOARD  |  12345  |  15
    2    |    PLAY  |  12345  |  15
    1    |    BATH  |  12345  |  15
```

This would be invoice 12344 has one dog (petid 12) who got 3 BOARD, 1 BATH, and invoice 12345 has two dogs (petid 14 and 15) who got 4 BOARD, 4 PLAY, 1 BATH and 4 BOARD, 2 PLAY, 1 BATH respectively. My table currently looks like this:

```
  DATE   | NAME | TOTAL | LNAME
---------|------|-------|-------
1/1/2013 | ODIE |   75  | SMITH
1/1/2013 | YODA |  115  | QWERT
1/1/2013 | C3PO |   90  | QWERT
```

and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  Invoices.InDate, 
  Pets.PtPetName, 
  SUM([IIQuantity]*[IIEach]) AS Total, 
  Clients.CLLastName
FROM 
  (((Clients INNER JOIN Pets ON Clients.CLSeq = Pets.PtOwnerCode) 
INNER JOIN 
  Invoices ON Clients.CLSeq = Invoices.InClientSeq) 
INNER JOIN 
  InvoiceItems ON (Invoices.InSeq = InvoiceItems.IIInvSeq) 
               AND (Pets.PtSeq = InvoiceItems.IIPetSequence)) 
INNER JOIN 
  Inventory ON InvoiceItems.IIItemCode = Inventory.InvSeq
WHERE (((Invoices.InDate)>#12/31/2012#))
GROUP BY Invoices.InDate, 
  Pets.PtPetName, 
  Clients.CLLastName,
  Invoices.InSeq
ORDER BY  Invoices.InSeq;
```

I'd like the table to somehow get another column for "Items" that would be the combined InvoiceItems.IIItemQuantity and InvoiceItems.IIItemCodeDesc. I've been looking at various ways to concatenate things, but nothing's come close to working (I've got a bunch of inner joins that I don't know if I need or not, or really much about what's going on with it all.)

Answer (score 1):

You can define [user defined function](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/creating-and-using-user-defined-functions-in-access/) for this purpose (just example):

```
Public Function GetItemList(invoice as Integer) As String
    Dim r As DAO.Recordset
    Dim result As String
    result = ""
    Set r = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Quantity, ItemDesc FROM your_joins WHERE Invoices.InvSeq =" & invoice & ";")
    do until r.EOF
        result = result & CStr(r![Quantity]) & " " & r![ItemDesc] & ", "
        r.MoveNext
    loop
    r.Close
    GetItemList = result
End Function
```

and use it in query like this:

```
select Invoices.invseq, GetItemList(Invoices.InvSeq) as ItemList from Invoices
```